# Nested columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**How do i achieve this in bootstrap**. [image: Bootstrap 3 nested columns]

I was able to create everything except the last col-md-8 using the following code:

```
    <div class="aaa">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background:yellow;height:100px;padding:20px;">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background:red;height:200px;padding:20px;">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background:blue;height:100px;padding:20px;">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background:orange;height:200px;padding:20px;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. Please see Frederic Le Feurmou's answer too.
1. **Removed nesting**
2. Added `float:right!important` `@media (min-width: 992px)` to the second div.

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="background:yellow;height:100px;"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 float" style="background:red;height:200px;"></div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="background:green;height:200px;"></div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue;height:100px;"></div>
<div class="col-md-8" style="background:purple;height:100px;"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) 
  { 
    .float
    {
      float:right!important;
    } 
  }
```

Link to bootply: http://www.bootply.com/Pgt6WdBhtt

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. You have to float one of your blocks.

Here is my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/8tvvrecw/2/

```
<div class="row" style="position:relative">
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="background:red; height:100px"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="position:absolute; right:0; background:purple; height:200px"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="background:black; height:200px"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background:blue; height:100px"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="background:green; height:100px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saw fiddle.. works great..but when i added it in my code the purple went up(somewhere above the page)..

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed that's because of the absolute position value on the div.

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed I added a relative positionning to the row parent so the absolute positionning should be relative to it. Does it work for you?

Comment: @FredericLeFeurmou : Sorry cannot check right now.. i will check later and comment here whether it is working or not.

Comment: @FredericLeFeurmou : Please see my answer and tell me if anything is wrong.